# Relialibility of user identity in actions-on-google for Dialogflow authentification

Tags: security, authentication, http-post, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am currently developing a strategy for Dialogflow on https://passportjs.org.

From what I've learnt, Dialogflow doesn't authenticate users. So I'm thinking about making a strategy (for passportjs) that identify users from every plateform differently (analyse the `originalRequest` differently for each plateform).

For example, the Telegram `originalRequest` has this field:

```
originalRequest.data.message.from.id
```

The Telegram says this field is a:

> "Unique identifier for this user or bot"

So I think it is safe to use it for authentication and identify every intent of my users fulfilled by my webhook.

I was wondering about the actions-on-google authentication and I found the field `originalRequest.data.user.userId`.

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/user-info) says:

> "Users can reset this identifier, so don't store important user data keyed off this identifier, because once it's reset, that information is no longer accessible by the user."

So the only reason to not trust the userId is because it can be reset? At the end of the documentation it says:

> User ID lifetime - User IDs are reset automatically after 30 days of inactivity or if users unlink their accounts on the device.

And:

> "If a registered user's voice isn't recognized by the device or no registered voice exists, then a different ID is used that is unique for just that conversation."

How to differentiate users from one other? Can some IDs be recycled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to differentiate users from each other is to use the `userId` field, as you've determined. On the AoG platform, the `userId` is meant to be used somewhat like a web cookie can be used - if you see it again, you are assured that this is the same user that used it last time. But if you see a new one, you have to assume that you've never seen this user before, even if it means they deleted the cookie.

To be clear - most of the time, the UserId will remain the same and you can expect returning users to have the same ID. This won't be true in only three cases:

1. They have reset the ID for this Action. So they have deliberately chosen to start over.
2. They didn't use the Action for 30 days, in which case it makes sense to treat them as a brand new user anyway in most cases.
3. They were not recognized as a normal user of this device, so they are treated anonymously. (This is the equivalent of the clunky "Do not remember me on this machine" setting you see on websites, which forces a session cookie rather than a persistent cookie.)

The phrasing is poor in the documentation - I think it is meant to remind developers that the user is ultimately in charge of their privacy. And Google both forces you to do the same and adopt policies that do so.

IDs will not be recycled. In fact, they won't even be re-used between different Actions, even for the same Assistant account.

*Summary*: If you see the same UserId, you can trust it is the same user you saw before. If you see a new one, assume they are a new user.

If you want a more robust way to identify users, you might consider using Account Linking which puts you in control of the identifying token. But that has significant additional overhead.

Be careful when using other authentication methods - Google limits how you're allowed to use them as part of an Action, and expressly forbids them in some cases. See the [General Policies](https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies#privacy_and_security) for details.

Comment: Differentiate users is great, but if the userId change every time, I would not be available to provide some persistance in apps. Also, I think about link persistent unique information like an email address or phone number to these ids. If an unknow ID appear, I will ask something like "have we already met before ?" and have some token verifications like an email or a sms that will prove the identity of my user (their ID can change but not their personnal information). It's seems okay ?

Comment: The UserID changes only under very specific, and fairly rare, circumstances. I've updated my answer to clarify.